# Fitbit not syncing

Tags: sync

How do I troubleshoot our Fitbit that doesn't seem to sync?  I installed using the PPA on a Lenovo E420 running Ubuntu 12.04.  Running `sudo start libfitbit_client` doesn't seem to do anything either.  Syncs fine under Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot libfitbit, check out the log at /var/log/libfitbit_client.log

```
tail -f /var/log/libfitbit_client.log
```

If it's working, you'll see transmission attempts and, ideally, a transmit success, followed by evidence of an update on the Fitbit website. Alternately, you'll see no device connected or transmission failures. You may have to kill and restart the libfitbit process.